# Jquery automatic scroll

Tags: jquery, scroll, anchor, bind

I'm looking for a way to scroll my page like this:
http://theartofraw.g-star.com

I haven't found a way to solve it.

I tried the following:

```
function scrollToAnchor(){ 
  $('body').bind('mousewheel', function(e){

  if(e.originalEvent.wheelDelta < 0) {

  $(document.body).animate({'scrollTop':  $('#js-anchor').offset().top}, 1000);

  state = 'scrolled';

  }else {
     //scroll up
     console.log('Up');
  }

    //prevent page fom scrolling
    return false;
  });

}
```

Looking forward for some hints.

Thank you in advance :-)

Answer (score 0):

look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6903650/programmatically-scrolling-a-set-of-divs-inside-a-parent-div) or use a [jquery plugin](http://archive.plugins.jquery.com/project/ScrollTo)